# Preserving insertion order across multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got some archived log files that I'd like to import into a MySQL database, for both archival and querying capabilities.

Each line in these log files represents a specific type of event. To illustrate this, here's an example, with each line being a different event type:

```
2013-01-15 03:30:08 - Failed login attempt for user 'helloworld' by 1.2.3.4
2013-01-15 03:30:08 - User 'helloworld' successfully logged in from 1.2.3.4
2013-01-15 03:30:08 - User 'helloworld' issued command 'randomcommand'
```

Note the timestamps, as that is relevant to the question.

My initial thought was to create a table for each event - `failed_logins`, `successful_logins`, `commands`, etc.

The problem with that approach is, when multiple events occur in the same second (the timestamps only have second-level precision), because they're in different tables I have no way of knowing the actual order they occurred in.

My next thought was to use one table, with the primary key preserving the order, but this would quickly get out of hand with all the event types. (There are more than this.)

```
CREATE TABLE log_lines (
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    type INT, // 1 = failed_login, 2 = command, ...
    failed_logins_user VARCHAR(32),
    failed_logins_ip VARCHAR(15),
    commands_user VARCHAR(32),
    commands_command VARCHAR(128)
);
```

I feel like there's a better way of accomplishing this.

To sum it up, my goal is to have the data queryable while also preserving the order each event occurred in the log file. How should I go about this?

Comment: just how many event types are there?

Comment: 30 total, with most containing 2 or more fields.

Comment: I cannot see why the option "primary key preserving the order" is not that good. What you can do is to "prepair" the file before inserting in the database. For example, you can grep it to get just the event types you want (`egrep "event1|event2|...|eventk" yourfile  > filetoexport`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution: use two tables for every line: one to store the columns common to all events, like a sequence number (an `AUTO_INCREMENT` column) and the timestamp, and one specifc to the event to give the other details. You can first insert into the common table, and then use the ID generated there as a unique foreign key in the other tables.

But also remember that `NULL` values usually only occupy one bit of data, so a single table with many columns that are only needed for some event types can be the better solution. It depends on your queries: if you usually query events of all types in order, a single table would be better, whereas extracting specific events of a given kind might be better suited by using different tables.

> ```
> type INT, // 1 = failed_login, 2 = command, ...
> ```

You might be better off using an `enum` for this kind of column.